# Tax calculation, rounding not valid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, tax-calculation

We use an MG 2.3.4 store and pricing is without tax. German tax is 19%. Today I learned, in Germany, you have to round your tax mathematically correct. So

```
133.60 x 19% = 25.384 => rounded to 25.38
```

But our Magento installation calculates a tax of 25.39. How can I change this behavior with a configuration or external component?

Answer (score 0):

I know this coming late but just in case someone is searching in the future for this.

The problem is that Magento calculates prices to TWO decimals. So the rounding becomes out usually when multiple lines are on the order as Magento adds up the tax per line normally

EG
Item 1 is 5.50. Tax at 19% = 1.045 - Round to 1.05
Item 3 is 4.50. Tax at 19% = 0.855 - Round to 0.86

Magento will now add 1.05 + 0.86 = 1.91

However, the sum SHOULD be (5.50 + 4.50) x 0.19 = 1.90 - Oops 0.01 out!

What you need to do is override the price rounding at the LOWEST level and use 4DP

So create a plugin :

```
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency">
        <plugin name="pricedecimals" type="MyCompany\Directory\Plugin\PriceDecimalsPlugin"/>
    </type>
```

Now the code :

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\Directory\Plugin;

use Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency;

/**
 * Plugins to control advanced price rounding requirements
 */
class PriceDecimalsPlugin extends PriceCurrency
{
    /**
     * Use 4dp for price calculations
     *
     * @param PriceCurrency $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param $price
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function aroundRound(
        PriceCurrency $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $price
    ) {
        // Call but ignore parent method
        $proceed($price);

        return round($price, 4);
    }

    /**
     * Override default precision for certain currency codes
     *
     * @param PriceCurrency $subject
     * @param $amount
     * @param null $scope
     * @param null $currency
     * @param int $precision
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeConvertAndRound(
        PriceCurrency $subject,
        $amount,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null,
        $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION)
    {
        $currentCurrency = $this->getCurrency($scope, $currency);

        // Special precision exceptions for currencies
        switch ($currentCurrency->getCurrencyCode()) {
            case 'GBP':
                $precision = 4;
                break;

            default:
                // Nothing required
        }

        return [$amount, $scope, $currency, $precision];
    }
}
```

The **aroundRound()** is the crucial one.

The **beforeConvertAndRound** is optional can precision for display can be set per currency.

In the above
Item 1 is 5.50. Tax at 19% = 1.045
Item 3 is 4.50. Tax at 19% = 0.855

Magento will now add 1.045 + 0.855 = 1.90 (this would then be rounded)

Correct!